# After how many rows is temp table column size determined?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

After how many rows is temp table column size determined?

For example, let's say the following query returns 10,000 rows:

```
select Name, LastName, Resume into #temp from Employee
```

All three columns in table Employee are varchar, but Employee.Resume (varchar(500)) can range from 20 chars to 400 chars. And if I run that query without the `INTO` clause, I will see that the longer Employee.Resume values are almost at the end of the 10,000 rows.

Does the INTO clause consider the whole result set when dumping the results into the temp table? Or does it use the first X rows to determine the sizes? Or does it just "inherit" the column sizes from the original table(s)?

I'm almost certain it copies the sizes from the original columns since I queried `tempdb.sys.columns`, but I just wanted to check.

Thanks.

Comment: The data types are determined independently of the `into` clause.  I think SQL Server would just use the sizes of the input columns in this case for the types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It copies the data types of the original columns.  It does not try to do any averaging of data lengths or precision.  There are a couple of exceptions relating to `FILESTREAM` (converted to `VARBINARY(MAX)`) and `IDENTITY` columns (sometimes not kept) though

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx):

> The format of new_table is determined by evaluating the expressions in the select list. The columns in new_table are created in the order specified by the select list. Each column in new_table has the same name, data type, nullability, and value as the corresponding expression in the select list. The IDENTITY property of a column is transferred except under the conditions defined in "Working with Identity Columns" in the Remarks section.
>
> ...
>
> **Data Types**
>
> The FILESTREAM attribute does not transfer to the new table. FILESTREAM BLOBs are copied and stored in the new table as varbinary(max) BLOBs. Without the FILESTREAM attribute, the varbinary(max) data type has a limitation of 2 GB. If a FILESTREAM BLOB exceeds this value, error 7119 is raised and the statement is stopped.
>
> When an existing identity column is selected into a new table, the new column inherits the IDENTITY property, unless one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The SELECT statement contains a join.
> - Multiple SELECT statements are joined by using UNION.
> - The identity column is listed more than one time in the select list.
> - The identity column is part of an expression.
> - The identity column is from a remote data source.
>
> If any one of these conditions is true, the column is created NOT NULL instead
> of inheriting the IDENTITY property. If an identity column is required in the new table but such a column is not available, or you want a seed or increment value that is different than the source identity column, define the column in the select list using the IDENTITY function. See "Creating an identity column using the IDENTITY function" in the Examples section below.

Answer (score 2):

As explained on the Microsoft website for the `INTO` clause:

> The format of new_table is determined by evaluating the expressions in
>   the select list. The columns in new_table are created in the order
>   specified by the select list. Each column in new_table has the same
>   name, data type, nullability, and value as the corresponding
>   expression in the select list.

In your specific instance, the data type would be whatever the data type is of the underlying column (in this case, `VARCHAR(500)`). If you were to do something like append another string to the column, for example `'RESUME: ' + E.resume`, then SQL Server would potentially change the data type based on its normal rules for expression data types. You can find those rules on the Microsoft website as well.

Comment: And the documentation is wrong because the column size is *not* determined by evaluating expressions.